# SAS: PROC REPORT or STYLE Double Outside Border, Solid Inside Border

Tags: css, templates, formatting, sas, proc-report

I need to format tables in an output RTF file (to be saved as a Word .docx file) with double outside border and solid inside border as such:

[image]

Is this possible to do with `PROC REPORT` using some sort of `STYLE` or `COMPUTE` statement? I've tried creating CSS templates but am having trouble with the language.

```
DATA TEST;
    INPUT CAR $12. YEAR;
    DATALINES;
    CHEVY   2001
    FORD    2005
    HONDA   2008
    ;
RUN;

ODS RTF FILE= "C:\Users\Documents\SAS Example Code\Test.rtf" STYLE=STATISTICAL;
PROC REPORT DATA = TEST NOWD;
    COLUMN CAR YEAR;
    DEFINE CAR / DISPLAY "Car";
    DEFINE YEAR / DISPLAY "Year";
    COMPUTE;

        /* insert code here to produce double outside border, solid inside border? */

    ENDCOMP;
RUN;
ODS RTF CLOSE;
```

Or, if I were to create a custom SAS style with the code, how could I achieve this?

```
PROC TEMPLATE;
   DEFINE STYLE STYLES.DOUBLEBORDER;
   PARENT = STYLES.RTF;
   STYLE USERTEXT FROM USERTEXT /
      TEXTALIGN = LEFT
      FONTSTYLE = ROMAN
      FONTSIZE = 3.5;
   STYLE FONTS /
      'DOCFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2)
      'HEADINGFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2,BOLD)
      'HEADINGEMPHASISFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2,BOLD)
      'FIXEDEMPHASISFONT' = ("<MONOSPACE>, COURIER, MONOSPACE",2)
      'FIXEDSTRONGFONT' = ("<MONOSPACE>, COURIER, MONOSPACE",2,BOLD)
      'FIXEDHEADINGFONT' = ("<MONOSPACE>, COURIER, MONOSPACE",2)
      'BATCHFIXEDFONT' = ("SAS MONOSPACE, <MONOSPACE>, COURIER, MONOSPACE",2)
      'FIXEDFONT' = ("<MONOSPACE>, COURIER",2)
      'EMPHASISFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2)
      'STRONGFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2,BOLD)
      'TITLEFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",3,BOLD)
      'TITLEFONT2' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2,BOLD);
   STYLE DATA /
      VERTICALALIGN = CENTER
      TEXTALIGN = CENTER
      FONTSIZE = 10PT
      FONTFAMILY = "ARIAL";
   STYLE TABLE /
      FRAME = BOX
      BORDERWIDTH = 1
      VERTICALALIGN = CENTER
      TEXTALIGN = CENTER
      FONTSIZE = 10
      CELLPADDING = 1.4
      BORDERSPACING = 0.7;
   STYLE HEADER /
      VERTICALALIGN = CENTER
      TEXTALIGN = CENTER
      FONTWEIGHT = BOLD
      FONTSIZE = 10PT
      FONTFAMILY = "ARIAL";
   STYLE ROWHEADER /
      VERTICALALIGN = CENTER
      TEXTALIGN = CENTER
      FONTSIZE = 10
      FONTFAMILY = "ARIAL";
   STYLE FOOTER /
      VERTICALALIGN = CENTER
      TEXTALIGN = CENTER
      FONTSIZE = 10
      FONTFAMILY = "ARIAL";
   STYLE COLOR_LIST /
      'LINK' = BLUE
      'BGH' = WHITE
      'FG' = BLACK
      'BG' = WHITE;
   STYLE BODY FROM DOCUMENT /
      MARGINBOTTOM = 1IN
      MARGINTOP = 1IN
      MARGINRIGHT = 1IN
      MARGINLEFT = 1IN;
END;
```

Comment: What version of SAS are you running?  If it's 9.4 you can use an actual CSS file to do your styling.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work properly using CSS, but i'm not an expert in CSS by any means.  If you know CSS but need to know how to use a CSS stylesheet in SAS, feel free to post a question related to that!

Comment: I'm using  9.4 now and have a brief CSS stylesheet set up, but again I cannot figure out how to add these darn outside borders. The best method I have now is creating a one-click VBA macro that automatically applies these borders to all tables in Word.

Comment: The outside borders are done through `borderstyle=double` in SAS or similar in CSS, but what I had trouble with was getting them to override the cell borders.  Turn off the cell borders and it's easy.  It might be an issue with border collapse but I couldn't work it out.  You might want to repost this as a CSS specific question, unless you do know how to get it to work in HTML and it's just when you use it in SAS that it doesn't work.  You could also try posting on communities.sas.com and see if Cynthia or one of the folks there can give you better advice since apparently it's vacation here...